# Why does my Angular http.delete send "null" instead of null?

Tags: angular

I have the following in my Angular service:

```
this.$http.delete<void>(ApiDomain.superPlan, `/v1/Attendance?resultEventId=${resultEventId}&dueEventId=${dueEventId}`)
```

And this is the signature of the C# method being called:

```
        [HttpDelete(),
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string resultEventId, string dueEventId)
```

The dueEventId passed in is sometimes null. Yet in the C# method, its value is "null" instead of null. How do I pass the actual null value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse null query parameters in AspNet Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478601/parse-null-query-parameters-in-aspnet-core)

Comment: Is this modern angular, or angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

When JavaScript is concatenating strings, if it comes across `null` it will insert "null" into the given string.

```
console.log(`/v1/Attendance?resultEventId=${1}&dueEventId=${null}`);
// output: /v1/Attendance?resultEventId=1&dueEventId=null
```

To avoid that, you can  avoid including the `dueEventId` query parameter at all if its value is null. Or leave the value empty: ASP.NET Core will interpret an empty string as `null`, as pointed out by Heretic Monkey in the comments.

Comment: Or pass the key without a value (e.g. `dueEventId=`), as described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite to ommit param with null value

```
let params=new HttpParams().append("resultEventId",""+resultEventId})
if(dueEventId){
   params=params.append("dueEventId",""+dueEventId);
}
this.$http.delete<void>(ApiDomain.superPlan, `/v1/Attendance`,{params});
```

otherwise you are sending `dueEventId="null"` which is exactly what you observe.