# AngularJS $http.get which contains a parameter with null value

Tags: angularjs

I've got a strange issue and can't figure it out. When I'm calling `$http.get` with params like

```
{oneId: 111
 twoId: 222
 stringValue: null}
```

then `stringValue` is absent and the request goes like

`http://my-uri.com/action?oneId=111&twoId=222`

But if `stringValue` setted as `undefined` then it goes ok. What's wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is a reserved keyword, that's why it's behaving like that. You can resolve this in a number of way -

1. as you are using asp.net web api - you can re-write your action -

```
public IHttpActionResult someAction(long oneId, long twoId, string stringValue = null)
```

In this way if `stringValue` doesn't get passed in param, then it will be received as null.

2. you can send `null` as string int the `get` method -

```
{oneId: 111
 twoId: 222
 stringValue: "null"}
```

Sending an empty string(`""`) instead of `"null"` is also an option.

3. Also as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255151/9041122) answer - sending url encoded null value(%00) will also work.

Comment: thanks! will be great if you will post links to docs to proof that (that `null` is reserved keyword)

Comment: @anatol, here you go [null reserved keyword](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)