# Python Requests - send null as query params value

Tags: python, python-requests, query-string

My URL can take null as a value for a query param like so:

```
https:/api.server.com/v1/users/?parent=null
```

When I'm trying to send the request in Python using Requests, I'm passing `None`:

```
requests.get(
    BASE_URL + USER_URL,
    headers = get_headers(),
    timeout = 60,
    params = {
        'parent': None
    }
)
```

However, it seems to skip the query param `parent` if it's set to `None`. How can I force it?

Comment: Did you try `'parent': 'null'`?

Comment: you can pass it as string ,what is the purpose of passing nul in param ?

Comment: Pass it as an empty string

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass `null` values with the `requests` package as it's the default behavior as stated in the docs:

[*Note that any dictionary key whose value is None will not be added to the URL’s query string.*](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Some solutions:

1. Maybe you can assume that not having it at the backend is `null`, or;
2. You can pass an empty string, or;
3. Pass a non-existent ID like `0`/`-1`, or;
4. Pass a boolean param like `parent=false` or `no-parent=true`.
5. I would not recommend passing the string `'null'` as it can be interpreted differently depending on the backend framework you're using. But if that's the case you can do so.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

None param will be skipped as if such a param is not set.

import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/events', params = {
'param1': None,
'param2':'',
'param3':'param_val'
})
print(r.url)

Result : http://localhost:9090/events?param2=&param3=param_val

Answer (score 1):

As @lepsch has mentioned, the `requests` library will not add `None` values to your query parameters. However, I feel like there is a misunderstanding in the entire question.

The URL `https:/api.server.com/v1/users/?parent=null` does not have the query parameter set to `None`. It is in fact set to `'null'`, which is actually a string with the data "null" inside of it. Therefore, if you want to do this, all you have to do is change `None` in your request to `'null'`:

```py
requests.get(
    BASE_URL + USER_URL,
    headers = get_headers(),
    timeout = 60,
    params = {
        'parent': 'null'
    }
)

# This will request
# https:/api.server.com/v1/users/?parent=null
```

However, if you want a true null value, then you should consider either putting an empty string value... :

```py
...
params = {
    'parent': ''
}
...

# This will request
# https:/api.server.com/v1/users/?parent=
```

... or use the actual null encoded character, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255151/11985743):

```py
requests.get(
    BASE_URL + USER_URL + "?parent=%00", # Must be added directly, as to not encode the null value
    headers = get_headers(),
    timeout = 60
)

# This will request
# https:/api.server.com/v1/users/?parent=%00
```